# How to remove horizontal page-break line (dotted and bold) that appear on tables in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, css

### Background

I used a method [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683637/1779823) by downloading the Chrome plugin [User JavaScript & CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld/related?hl=en) by adding the following code:

```
.kix-page-compact::before{
    border-top: none;
}
```

As a result, I was able to remove this horizontal, dotted line that you can see below:

[image]

### Problem

However, the bold line, which splits table rows in random places, still appears:

[image]

What CSS should I use to remove this?

Comment: It's great that you are sharing the answer that you found on [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts about finding CSS selectors on  Google Docs / Google apps. Anyway, perhaps your question should be about how to use your favorite web browser's developer tools to find the CSS style / selector that you are looking for.

Comment: By the other hand, it looks like this question is asking for the technologies behind a web app which nowadays is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Rubén I always understood that close reason to be so people don't ask what software runs Facebook, Google, etc., asking about what CSS to use for removing a line seems on quite a different level.

Comment: @Mast do you know about similar questions on this site?

Comment: Few days ago (Feb 2022) Google announced the launch of "Pageless" mode in Google Docs. Open a document in Google Docs web app then click on the File menu > Page Setup. The page setup dialog now shows a "Pageless" tab.